# google spreadsheet addon submenu disappears after creating a new spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I have a google spreadsheet addon with the following triggers.

```
function onOpen(e) {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();;
  var menuItems = [{name: 'Import json', functionName: 'jsonLoadInit'}];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Magic-Json', menuItems);
}

function onInstall(e) {

    onOpen(e);
}
```

When I first install the addon from a sheet, it is working fine. Shows both menu and menu items. But when I try to access the addon from a new spreadsheet, it is not showing the menu items .

Comment: If you are creating a new sheet within the same Spreadsheet, this should not happen. In that case, I would suggest to report the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list). However, if you're creating a new Spreadsheet, it is expected to happen that way as you need to install the add-on to the new Spreadsheet as you need to authorize the add-on. Also, your code itself suggests the `onOpen` function to run once `onInstall` has been initiated.

Comment: I have seen many  add-ons , once installed on a spreadsheet, used to work on any other spreadsheet of that user. In my case it shows menu in any spreadsheet, but sub menus are only showed in the installed spreadsheet.